# WCF and AD LDS and Basic Authentication

Tags: wcf, active-directory, basic-authentication, adam

I'm not sure what changes are necessary in web.config on the server.  I have a WCF service using basic authentication.  Currently its working against Active Directory.  What changes are necessary so it authenticates against AD LDS instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change your connection string in the web.config file to point at your AD LDS instance instead of the current Active Directory instance. They're both LDAP servers so everything else should be the same.

If you post your web.config file I can give you more detailed advice.